# kotlin | Settings Fragment | Dark mode

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I'm trying to swap between themes (light and dark). And i use a settingsFragment (inherited from PreferenceFragmentCompat() ). There i have a lateinit var - activity for calling a function in MainActivity that helps me to swap(switch) between dark/light mode.

The problem is: when i change theme, the MainActivity updates and theme changed, but when i switch it again i have an error that activity variable hasnt been initialized (but i initialize it in OnCreate() )

Settings Fragment:

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    lateinit var **activity**: MainActivity

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {

        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)

        val themePreference : Preference = findPreference("theme")!!
        val fontPreference : Preference = findPreference("font_list")!!
        val langPreference : Preference = findPreference("lang_list")!!

        themePreference.onPreferenceClickListener = Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {

            activity.setTheme()

            true
        }

    }

}
```

MainActivity.setTheme():

```
fun setTheme(){
    val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    val isNightMode: Boolean? = sharedPreferences?.getBoolean("theme",false)

    if(isNightMode == true){
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
    }
    else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
    }

}
```

Im tried to use a

```
this.getTheme().applyStyle(android.R.style.ThemeOverlay_Material_Dark, true);
```

and

```
this.setTheme(android.R.style.ThemeOverlay_Material_Light)
```

but it doesnt work correctly.
If someone have an idea, please, tell me

Comment: Where are you setting the Activity property?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one activity then it's ok, but if you have multiple activity you will need one baseActivity to set it for all activities which implements from it. And you need to use `setTheme` method above `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` like below:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```